# Links of second level menu don't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, navigation, mobile-safari, usability

I am working on a wordpress theme based on _s (with some modifications) and bootstrap 3.3.2.

In the mobile devices, the submenus of primary navigation are already expanded, but there is a problem on iPhones: The link of second level menu don't work, if you click on them just nothing happens.

This is the url of the website: www.machenergyaustralia.com.au/

Tested with iPhone 6s, ios10 and safari.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to inproper `<a>` tag.

**1)** Check whether the `<A href="">` has content like:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

because mobile safari doesn't take `<A>` without href as anchor, when catching click events on this element.

Sometimes (I met with this problem), in template, there is a href or href content missing.

**2)** If another element is intended to be clicked (like `span` for example, you probably may need to create such an element and retype `<span>` to `<a href="...">`). In bootstrap's javascript/css environment it can be a must.
**Mobile safari doesn't like to catch click events on elements other than `<a>`**

Comment: Hi @pedrouan, thank you so much for your reply but I think they are not good for my case because the menu is just created using the WP function wp_nav_menu and all elements of the menu are _Pages_ of WordPress, not custom links, so all href are ok and follow all the standards.